# Why is there one push in iOS but two notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send a push notification from the backend of the application in the iOS and Android application
I look through the following in my push request:

> Array ( [registration_ids] => Array ( [0] => test_token ) [notification] => Array ( [title] => Title of notification [body] => Text of notification [sound] => 1 [content_available] => 1 [priority] => high [badge] => 4 [smallIcon] => small_logo [click_action] => .NoticeFullController ) [data] => Array ( [short_text] => Short text of notification [selectNotice] => 123 [selectStatus] => 4 ) [apns] => Array ( [headers] => Array ( [apns-priority] => 5 ) [payload] => Array ( [aps] => Array ( [category] => notice_push ) ) ) )

There is no problem with the Android application, but the following happens on iOS:

1. If the application is in the background or the notification is closed, one is displayed, but when you click on it, the main page of the application opens, and you need to open a page with the full view of the notification with the ID from the 'selectNotice' field in the request if it is greater than 0, otherwise the main page.
2. If the application is open, then at the first start there is only the sound of the application and nothing more. And a notification should be displayed, and not just its sound.
3. The next time you send a push, two notifications are displayed, one of which is from the background mode, the second is created by my code, but you need only one. And when you click on it, the main page of the application opens, but you need to open the page with the full view of the notification with the ID from the 'selectNotice' field in the request if it is greater than 0, otherwise the main page.

Help deal with pushing in iOS. Thank you very much in advance. My AppDelegate Code:

```
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // Уведомления в фоне
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in})

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    //Handle the notification
    completionHandler(
        [UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "notice_push")
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    if let title = userInfo["title"]
    {
        content.title = title as! String
    }

    if let short_text = userInfo["short_text"]
    {
        content.body = short_text as! String
    } else if let short_text = userInfo["body"]
    {
        content.body = short_text as! String
    }

    if let badge = userInfo["badge"]
    {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge as! Int
    }
    //category = ".NoticeFullController";

    content.userInfo = userInfo
    content.sound = .default()
    content.threadIdentifier = "my-notice"
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        content.summaryArgument = "notification"
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"notice", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if let getError = error {
            print(getError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two notifications because `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])` is called when your app is in Foreground, and when you click on the notification when the app is in Background.

This method is deprecated.

You have to implement only this two delegate methods.

`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)` is called when the app is in foreground

`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` is called when you click on the notification when the app is in the background.

Comment: Thanks. How can I launch the selected page when I click on notifications and pass the data to it from 'selectNotice'? Thanks